# Appending URL parameter to end of img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, parameters, append

I'd like to use JS or JQuery to grab a specific URL parameter and append it to an IMG SRC tag I have embedded in a custom code block on my landing page. Example below:

Example URL - `https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=test&email=test@test.com`

Desired IMG SRC - `<img src="https://www.example.com/example.jpg?email=test@test.com">`

I've combed through a couple of articles that present similar solutions (usually the image src URL itself), but I haven't been able to get it to work - just out of my depth.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Danish - thank you for your feedback. In this example, what would the corresponding HTML block for the image look like? < img src = ? >

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is our URL: [https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=test&email=test@test.com";](https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=test&email=test@test.com%22;)

```
const url = window.location.href;
    const email = url.split("email=")[1];
    const imgSrc = "https://www.example.com/example.jpg?email=" + email;
    const imgTag = "<img src='" + imgSrc + "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [danish's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555625/danish) answer:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function setToImg(url,param,imageId,imageUrl){
        const urlParam =  url.split(''+param+'=')[1];
        const result =  decodeURI(urlParam).trim();
        const imgSrc = imageUrl+'?'+param+'='+result;
        $('#'+imageId).attr('src',imgSrc);
    }

    setToImg('https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=test&email=test@test.com','email','myImage','image-name.jpeg');

    //helper for run function:
    //setToImg('your_url_whith_params','param','your_image_id','your_image_url_without_params');
    //for top page url:
    //setToImg(window.location.href,'email','myImage','image-name.jpeg');

    console.log($('div').html()); //for test - remove this line.

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img id="myImage"></div>
```

> **UPDATE**: for get *image past src* and append *new src*:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function setToImg(url,param,imageId){
        const urlParam =  url.split(''+param+'=')[1];
        const result =  decodeURI(urlParam).trim();
        const imageUrl = $('#'+imageId).attr('src');
        const imgSrc = imageUrl+'?'+param+'='+result;
        $('#'+imageId).attr('src',imgSrc);
    }

    setToImg('https://www.example.com/page?utm_source=test&email=test@test.com','email','myImage');

    //helper for run function:
    //setToImg('your_url_whith_params','param','your_image_id');
    //for top page url:
    //setToImg(window.location.href,'param','your_image_id');

    console.log($('div').html());  //for test - remove this line.

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img id="myImage" src="https://example.com/img/image.jpeg"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Ramin, thank you for the feedback. The part I'm not quite understanding is the setToImage line and the helper you've laid out for it. In my case, the &email=test@test.com will be unique for every visitor to the page, so I'm not able to hardcode a specific email address into 'your_url_whith_params' - could you elaborate?

Comment: you're welcome. for the page you are in : `setToImg(window.location.href,'email','your_image_id');` If not, tell me.

Comment: Please use the updated code. (The second code in my answer)